# Ubuntu 16.04 - Cannot reach the Internet

Tags: networking, networkmanager

```
root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# Liveliness Interface
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
address 192.0.2.100/24

dns nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.0.2.1 1.1.1.1

Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# See LP: #1262951
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg
```

root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
 address 192.0.2.100
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.0.2.0
 broadcast 192.0.2.255
 gateway 192.0.2.1
dns nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.0.2.1
```

Systemctl is loaded and status is active !!

```
root@ubuntu:~# systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor prese
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2020-04-03 09:24:56 UTC; 59s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 1485 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=
  Process: 1479 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [
 Main PID: 1485 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 03 09:24:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Apr 03 09:24:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

Cannot reach the Internet

```
root@ubuntu:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3022ms
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error which explains why the update fails. Then, you can check on the network issue with _ip -a_ as _ipconfig_ is depreciated. BTW, which release of Ubuntu is installed?

Comment: Thanks. I did try that. Unfortunately could not get any far. I run Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Did you look at the configuration file error that is reported right there in the log?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Your effort is more towards asking this question, than reading up the error logs, I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

(You can actually have `dns nameservers` or `dns-nameservers` so that part doesn't matter).

For what does matter, take note of the error in the output of `systemctl status networking.service` regarding the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

You have a syntax error in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

Change this:

```
source

/etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg
```

to this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg
```

And then start the service.

Comment: Thanks. I did make the change to dns nameservers. Same error persists.

Comment: @juns Update the question with what is in `/etc/network/interfaces` and the output from `systemctl status networking` after making the changes. Make sure that you are including the entirety of the file.

Comment: And take note for when this happens in the future that this error message in the log _tells you exactly what line of what file_ to look at, as M. Riley has just demonstrated.

Comment: Tell him to add `--full` option to `systemctl`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help